# apt-get 'deb' is not known in /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I get following error trying to excute apt-get update

> 'deb' is not known in /etc/apt/sources.list

My sources.list

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

I looked in various forums but couldn't find a solution for it. It's not a typo.

The output of

```
hex -C /etc/apt/sources.list
```

doesn't show anything suspicious. Am I missing some configuration for apt?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on the Unix/Linux exchange

Answer (score 0):

my sources.list has the following source entries uncommented. maybe you should compare these with yours.

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security universe restricted multiverse main
deb http://ke.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe restricted multiverse main
deb http://ke.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports universe restricted multiverse main
```

And in the future I think you will get better help by posting ubuntu related questions to [unix and linux stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or to [dedicated to ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)